# git filter-branch get only changed files?

Tags: git, phpcs

We want to run `git filter-branch` over a large codebase reformatting PHP files. Since we have over 21k commits `phpcbf` wants to format the whole codebase every commit of `filter-branch`. Is it possible to get just the files that have changed for each commit and format them specifically? Something like...

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter \
 'FILES=$(<something> | grep .php) php /usr/local/bin/phpcbf.phar $FILES || true'
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'phpcbf $(\
  git show $GIT_COMMIT --name-status | egrep ^[AM] |\
    grep .php | cut -f2)' -- --all
```

Just to give a quick overview of what it’s doing:

- `git show $GIT_COMMIT --name-status` would return all the modified files for that commit.
- `egrep ^[AM]` filters down the statues to Added and Modified only. No need to try and format files that are being Deleted.
- `grep .php` to only format PHP files.
- `cut -f2` removes the status prefix from the list so we just get the raw file paths.

See my blog post for more details: https://elliot.land/post/reformatting-your-codebase-with-git-filter-branch

Comment: Elliot's solution got me 98% of the way there. It seems like some behavior in `git diff` during a filter-branch has changed (I'm running git 2.10.2). It was constantly comparing to my latest HEAD, rather than the filtered commit's parent. I was able to change Elliot's code slightly to make it work.

Instead of `git diff --cached --name-status` during the filter, I used `git show $GIT_COMMIT --name-status`. `$GIT_COMMIT` is automatically set during each step of the `filter-branch`.

Comment: I found that `git show $GIT_COMMIT --name-only --pretty=oneline|tail -n +2` is more robust than `git show $GIT_COMMIT --name-status | egrep ^[AM]` Note that it will also return deleted files so you might need to test for the file existence.